# Diplomacy game, year made

Tags: diplomacy

I have what appears to be an old version of Diplomacy. It is sealed in the box so I can't tell much about it. The side says model 9100, made in USA by Games Research. Inc., Boston, MA. 02118

Can anyone tell me the year or years this would have been made?

Comment: If you are able to give us a picture, you may improve your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: [Here](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/cc/5c/e0/cc5ce053bcd1241f91e3fd2e0d33bc69.jpg) is an image of the Diplomacy box as it was sold in the early 1970's. This was the standard until Avalon Hill repackaged it as [this](https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/b6MAAOSw9MBi2aUd/s-l1200.webp) in the late 1970's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Games Research edition, [illustrated here](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/cc/5c/e0/cc5ce053bcd1241f91e3fd2e0d33bc69.jpg) and, revealed by a little squinting reading

> *Made in U.S.A. by Games Research Inc., Boston MA 02118*

as desired, apparently came out circa 1958 (given that Avalon Hill's 50th anniversary edition is dated 2008). I recall first seeing this edition in our History Department library in 1970.

> [image]

The above, as far as I can tell, was the only edition available until [Avalon Hill's bookcase edition](https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/b6MAAOSw9MBi2aUd/s-l1200.webp) came out in 1976:

> [image]